# XPath to find element based on another XPath element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an Java AST and I try to find a variable inside it via XPath.

Lets say the variable is called 'foobar' I could use

```
//VariableDeclarator/VariableDeclaratorId[@Image='foobar']
```

but what if I dont know the text 'foobar', but want to read it from another element

```
//VariableDeclarator/VariableDeclaratorId[@Image=//SynchronizedStatement/Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name]
```

the 'Name' node has the information 'foobar' in @Image, but `PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image]` does not work.

How must I rewrite the condition `//SynchronizedStatement/Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name` that it is the same as `@Image='foobar'` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath:-

```
//VariableDeclarator/VariableDeclaratorId[@Image=//SynchronizedStatement/Expression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name/@Image]
```